# Reshaping Pandas dataframe by months

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pivot, time-series

The task is to transform the below table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=700, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(700), index=index, columns=["values"])

df.groupby(by=[df.index.year, df.index.month]).sum()

In[1]: df

Out[1]: 
           values
2000 1   1.181000
     2  -8.005783
     3   6.590623
     4  -6.266232
     5   1.266315
     6   0.384050
     7  -1.418357
     8  -3.132253
     9   0.005496
     10 -6.646101
     11  9.616482
     12  3.960872
2001 1  -0.989869
     2  -2.845278
     3  -1.518746
     4   2.984735
     5  -2.616795
     6   8.360319
     7   5.659576
     8   0.279863
     9  -5.220678
     10  5.077400
     11  1.332519
```

such that it looks like this

```
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  
2000  1.2  -8.0 6.6  -6.3 1.2  0.4  -1.4 -3.1 0.0  -6.6 9.6  3.9    
2001  -0.9 -2.8 -1.5 3.0  -2.6 8.3  5.7  0.3  -5.2 5.1  1.3
```

Additionally I need to add an extra column which sums the yearly values like this

```
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec  Year
2000  1.2  -8.0 6.6  -6.3 1.2  0.4  -1.4 -3.1 0.0  -6.6 9.6  3.9  4.7
2001  -0.9 -2.8 -1.5 3.0  -2.6 8.3  5.7  0.3  -5.2 5.1  1.3       10.7
```

Is there a quick pandas pivotal way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `strftime('%b')` in your `groupby`

```
df['values'].groupby([df.index.year, df.index.strftime('%b')]).sum().unstack()
```

[image]

---

To preserve order of months

```
df['values'].groupby([df.index.year, df.index.strftime('%b')], sort=False).sum().unstack()
```

[image]

---

With `'Year'` at end

```
df['values'].groupby([df.index.year, df.index.strftime('%b')], sort=False).sum() \
    .unstack().assign(Year=df.groupby(df.index.year).sum())
```

[image]

Comment: This ones more Elegant! Nice hat!

Comment: @MYGz I saw yours and was jelous... 10 minutes later, I had my own /shrug

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=700, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(700), index=index, columns=["values"])

l = [df.index.strftime("%Y"), df.index.strftime("%b"), df.index.strftime("%d")]
df.index = l
df=df.groupby(level=[-3,-2]).sum().unstack(-1)
df['Year'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is very close to what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Only change is you need to `unstack` the `DF` to convert it into a wide format. Once you get the integer month numbers, you could convert these into a `datetime` by specifying `%m` directive as the format to be considered. After obtaining this, use it to retrieve it's string representation through the help of `strftime`.

Calculate the year by taking it's sum across columns by specifying `axis=1`.

```
np.random.seed(314)
fr = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
fr.columns = pd.to_datetime(fr.columns.droplevel(0), format='%m').strftime('%b')
fr['Year'] = fr.sum(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems the to be the correct answer to me. I will keep the question open for a short period.

Comment: @Pat, To be frank, piRSquared's answer is much better. Should go with his one.

Answer (score 0):

The extra `Year` column you can do by doing

```
df['Year'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

It will sum the dataframe row-wise (due to the `axis=1`), and storing it in a new column.